# CSS : start scroll bar from specific div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I am making a page in which header part is fixed , the center contents are scrolling. I want the header part to occupy whole page including scrollbar area , and I want the scroll bar to be appeared from below the header.

```css
.bg-dark{
  background:#3a3f51;
}
.bg-dark-header{
  position:fixed;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1000;
  top: 0;
  color:white;
}

.center_content{
  margin-top:40px;
  height:600px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="bg-dark bg-dark-header ">

  Header Text
</div>

<div class="center_content text-center">
Center Content
  Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content
</div>
```

So , I want a scroll-bar from `center-content` div and the header part should occupy whole width.

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `calc` property, in you case `.center_content{ height: calc(body height - header-height);}`

```
.center_content {
  margin-top: 60px;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```css
.bg-dark {
  background: #3a3f51;
}
.bg-dark-header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
}
.center_content {
  margin-top: 60px;
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="bg-dark bg-dark-header ">

  Header Text
</div>

<div class="center_content text-center">
  Center Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter
  Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter
  Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter
  Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter
  Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter
  Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter
  Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content Center ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter ContentCenter Content
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but scroll bar is hiding behind the header which i don't want.

Comment: Check updated answer, gave `margin-top:60px`, as same as header height.

Comment: still scrollbar is hiding behind the header. i want scrollbar to be started from center-content div.

Comment: It will do same as you want, just follow above snippet.

Comment: Glad! I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Change you css to the following:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bg-dark{
  background:#3a3f51;
}
.bg-dark-header{
  position:fixed;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:1000;
  top: 0;
  color:white;
}

.center_content{
  margin-top:60px;
  height:600px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

It removes the scroll bars of the whole page and adds bars to the `.center_content`.

I also corrected the `margin-top` of .center_content to match the height of the header.